# Hide div based on index

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to hide divs based on an index that I get. I am not sure how I can use that index to hide the div.

```
document.getElementById("medicalCard").style.display = "none";
```

The above line only caters for the first div but there can be multiple `medicalCard` divs

I get an index back correctly with my below method. I am just not sure how to append the index to the above code.

```
  removeMedicalProvider(index: number){
    console.log(index);
    this.delete.emit(index);
    document.getElementById("medicalCard").style.display = "none";
  }
```

HTML

```
<div id="medicalCard" class="card mb-4" *ngFor="let provider of companyMedicalAidProvider; let i = index;">
...
...
</div>
```

Comment: The id selector only returns 1 element since id's need to be unique. Use `querySelectorAll()` and use the css selectors to get the correct index.

Comment: You should never use duplicate IDs, rather use a class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css selectors you can select the correct index so you don't have to retrieve all the elements. Because `nth-child` start at 1 you can use `++index`.

```js
function hideIndex(index) {
  document.querySelector(`.card:nth-child(${++index})`).style.display = "none";
}
hideIndex(2);
```

```html
<div id="medicalCard" class="card mb-4">
  0
</div>
<div id="medicalCard" class="card mb-4">
  1
</div>
<div id="medicalCard" class="card mb-4">
  2
</div>
<div id="medicalCard" class="card mb-4">
  3
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done with an ID, because there should only be one element with a given ID. You can use classes for this, if you must.

For example, assuming your cards have the following HTML markup:

```
<li class="card mb-4 medical-provider" *ngFor="...">
  ...
</li>
```

you can select them by using `querySelectorAll`:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.medical-provider');
// hide the one at the given index
cards[index].style.display = 'none';
```